# DiscordJS ON/OFF Button Time Date Calculation

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to make a command with 2 buttons called ON and OFF and when user clicks the ON button, it calculates the date from when it was on and subtracts it from the off

How to make it I am really frustrating right now if you can help me

```
const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
  new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('onButton')
    .setLabel('ON')
    .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
  new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('offButton')
    .setLabel('OFF')
    .setStyle('DANGER'),
);

await message.reply({
  content: 'Click a button to start or stop the timer:',
  components: [row],
});

const filter = (interaction) =>
  interaction.customId === 'onButton' || interaction.customId === 'offButton';

const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({
  filter,
  time: 60000,
});

let timerStart;
let timerEnd;

collector.on('collect', (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.customId === 'onButton') {
    timerStart = new Date();
    interaction.reply({ content: 'Timer started!', ephemeral: true });
  } else if (interaction.customId === 'offButton') {
    timerEnd = new Date();
    if (timerStart) {
      const difference = timerEnd - timerStart;
      interaction.reply({
        content: `Timer stopped! Elapsed time: ${difference / 1000} seconds`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    } else {
      interaction.reply({
        content: 'Timer not started!',
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }
    collector.stop();
  }
});

collector.on('end', () => {
  message.edit({
    content: 'Timer session ended.',
    components: [],
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **new Date()** use **Date.now()** instead.

```js
let timerStart;
let timerEnd;

if (interaction.customId === 'onButton') {
    timerStart = Date.now();
}
else if (interaction.customId === 'offButton') {
    timerEnd = Date.now()
    
    let calculate = (timerEnd - timerStart) / 1000;
}
```

This should now return the time difference in seconds.

- Tip: It's usually a good idea to put your interaction replies in an **async function** and **await** it since interaction replies return a promise and, can evade error handling if not awaited properly.